# image data is diffenent after removing statement

Tags: python

I am making a flask server for an application and I made a **working** system that finds the current users profile photo ( windows 10 ) and will convert it to data/text and return it, it works properly but as soon as i add it to the server it stops working and will return a default pfp here is the script with the flask server implmentation and it works up untill you remove the `quit()` statment

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt
import re
import shutil
import base64
import sys


SGUPP_DIRECTORY = 0x01
SGUPP_DEFAULTDIRECTORY = 0x02
SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR = 0x80000000

def image_to_base64(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as image_file:
        base64_data = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
    return base64_data

def convert_image_to_base64():
    shell32 = ct.WinDLL("shell32.dll")
    SHGetUserPicturePathW = shell32[261]
    SHGetUserPicturePathW.argtypes = (wt.LPWSTR, wt.DWORD, wt.LPWSTR, wt.UINT)
    SHGetUserPicturePathW.restype = ct.c_long

    buf_len = 0xFF
    buf = ct.create_unicode_buffer(buf_len)
    flags = SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR
    res = SHGetUserPicturePathW(None, flags, buf, buf_len)
    output = "    SHGetUserPicturePathW returned {0:016X}\n    Path set to: [{1:s}]".format(res, buf.value)
    path_match = re.search(r"Path set to: \[(.*?)\]", output)
    if path_match:
        source_path = path_match.group(1)
        destination_path = "profile.jpg"
        print(source_path)
        shutil.copy(source_path, destination_path)
        
        # Convert the image to base64
        base64_data = image_to_base64(destination_path)
        return base64_data
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    datas = convert_image_to_base64()
    print(datas)































quit()
import flask
import subprocess
from flask_cors import CORS

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS = CORS(app)


@app.route("/profile")
def return_data(): 
    return datas

@app.route("/command/<command>")
def run_command(command):
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        output = result.stdout + result.stderr
        return output
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

@app.route("/email")
def get_registered_owner():
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(['systeminfo'], capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
        output = result.stdout

        owner_match = re.search(r'Registered Owner:\s*(.*)', output)
        if owner_match:
            registered_owner = owner_match.group(1).strip()
            return registered_owner
        else:
            return "Registered owner information not found."
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

@app.route("/username")
def username(): 
    return run_command("echo %username%").strip()

@app.route("/whoami")
def whoami():
    return run_command("whoami").strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**can't upload the data im getting as it would make the body 848484 lines **